# Spanning div over width remaining next to unordered list?

Tags: css, width, html

```
<div class="nav">
    <ul class="nav">
        <a class="nav" href="#">
            <li class="nav">item1</li>
        </a>
        <a class="nav" href="#">
            <li class="nav">item2</li>
        </a>
        <a class="nav" href="#">
            <li class="nav">item3</li>
        </a>
    </ul>
    <div class="line"></div>
</div>
```

This is my HTML navbar

CSS:

```
ul.nav {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 0;
}

li.nav {
    display:inline-block;
    border-bottom: 2px solid gray;
    padding: 15px 20px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 16px;
}
div.nav {
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

How do I style the div.line so it is exactly next to the list (right), fills the rest of the page (width) and has the same height as the ul.nav/div.nav?

Thanks,

Comment: could you provide an image of how it should look?

Comment: I created a fiddle for you: http://jsfiddle.net/7uZgW/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, sorry about the english level!

You can do something like:

```
.line {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: gray;
 }
```

e.g: http://jsfiddle.net/X8fE4/

That's basically turn the div.line into an absolute alement behind your navigation. It will have the width of the parent div.nav, it's not a beautiful solution, but is well supported :)

Comment: If I use the proposed styling, my div.line has the same height of the whole page, not just the div.nav?Why is this?

Comment: the div.line has the same height of the parent element (div.nav). be aware that the parent element, **div.nav**, should have the **position:relative**.

Answer (score 0):

this might help you:

preview: http://jsfiddle.net/webcarvers/7uZgW/3/embedded/result/
code: http://jsfiddle.net/webcarvers/7uZgW/3/

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("div.two").css({
    //-2 is for border width
    "width": ($(window).width() - $("div.nav").outerWidth() - 2) + "px",
        "height": ($("div.nav").height()-2) + "px"
});
});
```

Comment: How would you change this code, so it refreshes automatically? (while resizing the browser)

Comment: It works great in the fiddle, but when trying to use it I get: Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined 

How should I embed this in the html file?
Do I need jquery?

Comment: Added jquery and it almost works, I still get a width:0 though,

Comment: can you share your live code! I can help with that. You must be missing something.

Answer (score -1):

```
div.nav {
 display: flex;
 display: ms-flex;
 display: -webkit-flex;
{
```

Edit: You also need to add the property `flex-grow` to `.line`.

```
.line {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/eWHnU/